# bash loop taking extremely long time

Tags: bash

I have a list of times that I am looping through in the format HH:MM:SS to find the nearest but not past time. The code that I have is:

```
 for i in ${times[@]}; do
    hours=$(echo $i | sed 's/\([0-9]*\):.*/\1/g')
    minutes=$(echo $i | sed 's/.*:\([0-9]*\):.*/\1/g')
    currentHours=$(date +"%H")
    currentMinutes=$(date +"%M")
    if [[ hours -ge currentHours ]]; then
            if [[ minutes -ge currentMinutes ]]; then
            break
            fi
    fi
done
```

The variable times is an array of all the times that I am sorting through (its about 20-40 lines). I'd expect this to take less than 1 second however it is taking upwards of 5 seconds. Any suggestions for decreasing the time of the regular expression would be appreciated.

```
times=($(cat file.txt))
```

Here is a list of the times that are stored in a text file and are imported into the times variable using the above line of code.

```
6:05:00
6:35:00
7:05:00
7:36:00
8:08:00
8:40:00
9:10:00
9:40:00
10:11:00
10:41:00
11:11:00
11:41:00
12:11:00
12:41:00
13:11:00
13:41:00
14:11:00
14:41:00
15:11:00
15:41:00
15:56:00
16:11:00
16:26:00
16:41:00
16:58:00
17:11:00
17:26:00
17:41:00
18:11:00
18:41:00
19:10:00
19:40:00
20:10:00
20:40:00
21:15:00
21:45:00
```

Comment: [mcve] would be helpful for testing... (aka, show some input data)

Comment: I will add in the input items, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Matthew the contents of the array `times` would be particularly useful. Also, what is the expected output? It's likely that the two `sed` calls can be replaced with built-in string manipulation, which would be faster.

Comment: It is only expected to break from the loop with the last variables in the loop stored in hours and minutes. This is then echo'd out to the user afterwards.

Comment: Yup, that's a slow loop. (Every `$()` runs a subprocess). It's got some bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch, but nothing performance-related.

Comment: hm... using your data, and `time bash -x script` -  for me it finishes in `real 0m0,345s`

Comment: It'd be faster if you wrote it as `while IFS=: read hours minutes seconds` -- then you wouldn't need to run the `sed`s.

Comment: Also, why are you calculating `currentHours` and `currentMinutes` *inside* the loop, rather than outside of it?

Comment: `times=($(cat file.txt))` is actually a buggy way to populate an array -- it expands globs, so if you had a `*` in `file.txt`, you'd get a list of filenames in your array. In bash 4, you could use `readarray -t times <file.txt` or `mapfile -t times <file.txt`; for compatibility with bash 3, you could use `read -r -d '' -a times <file.txt || (( ${#times[@]} ))`.

Comment: I totally overthought having currentHours and currentMinutes in the loop, there is no need for it to be in there. I have removed it and that dramatically helped reduce the time.

Comment: *nod*. Other than the `date` calls, the `sed`s are the other thing that'll be eating your processing time.

Comment: BTW, I'm curious -- what's the platform you're testing on? (Even while there was much to improve in this code, the timings reported *are* fairly slow; unless it's a Raspberry Pi or somesuch, I'm wondering if you're on Cygwin -- `fork()` has never been optimized as effectively on Windows [where they have a quite different syscall that's the preferred way to launch an external process] as on Linux).

Comment: Yes, I am using cygwin currently. Have ubuntu on my home computer but am stuck using cygwin with my laptop for now.

Comment: There's also a problem with the time comparison logic; for example, if the current time is 5:59:00, the `[[ minutes -ge currentMinutes ]]` test will never be true (with the listed file contents). I'm pretty sure you want something like `(( hours > currentHours )) || (( hours == currentHours && minutes >= currentMinutes ))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the key things to understand in looking at bash scripts from a performance perspective is that while the bash interpreter is somewhat slow, the act of spawning an external process is *extremely* slow. Thus, while it can often speed up your scripts to use a single invocation of `awk` or `sed` to process a large stream of input, starting those invocations inside a tight loop will greatly outweigh the performance of those tools once they're running.

Any command substitution -- `$()` -- causes a second copy of the interpreter to be `fork()`ed off as a subshell. Invoking any command not built into bash -- `date`, `sed`, etc -- then causes a subprocess to be `fork()`ed off for that process, and then the executable associated with that process to be `exec()`'d -- something involves a great deal of OS-level overhead (the binary needs to be linked, loaded, etc).

---

This loop would be better written as:

```
IFS=: read -r currentHours currentMinutes < <(date +"%H:%M")
while IFS=: read -r hours minutes _; do
    if (( hours >= currentHours )) && (( minutes >= currentMinutes )); then
        break
    fi
done <file.txt
```

In this form only one external command is run, `date +"%H:%M"`, *outside* the loop. If you were only targeting bash 4.2 and newer (with built-in time formatting support), even this would be unnecessary:

```
printf -v currentHours '%(%H)T' -1
printf -v currentMinutes '%(%M)T' -1
```

...will directly place the current hour and minute into the variables `currentHours` and `currentMinutes` using only functionality built into modern bash releases.

---

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?
- [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Splitting_a_string_into_fields) - How can I do native string manipulations in bash? (Subsection: *"Splitting a string into fields"*)

Comment: What are those `-1`s at the end of the `printf` lines for?

Comment: @TomFenech, those are telling it what time to print, in seconds since the epoch -- it reads `-1` to mean "now".

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was unaware of the IFS command. That is a much quicker way of parsing my data than trying to call sed to regex continuously.

Comment: @MatthewBovolotto, ...so, IFS isn't a command; it's a variable that controls how the shell splits strings into individual words, and how `read` splits inputs into separate arguments. The `IFS=value read` format is just setting `IFS` to have that value for the duration of that one `read` invocation, just as how you can run `var1=val1 var2=val2 env` and have `var1` and `var2` both set for that `env` invocation, but not present after it exits.

Comment: Thanks as well for the documentation! I will check it out

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I'm not sure why it's taking an *extremely long time* but there are certainly some things which could be made more efficient.

```
currentHours=$(date +"%H")
currentMinutes=$(date +"%M")

for time in "${times[@]}"; do
    IFS=: read -r hours minutes seconds <<<"$time"
    if [[ hours -ge currentHours && minutes -ge currentMinutes ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

This uses `read`, a built-in command, to split the text into variables, rather than calling external commands and creating subshells.

I assume that you want the script to run so quickly that it's safe to reuse `currentHours` and `currentMinutes` within the loop.

Note that you can also just use awk to do the whole thing:

```
awk -F: -v currentHours="$(date +"%H") -v currentMinutes="$(date +"%M")" '
    $1 >= currentHours && $2 >= currentMinutes { print; exit }' file.txt
```

Just to make the program produce some output, I added a `print`, so that the last line is printed.

Comment: `<<<"$time"` is actually a tiny bit slow with current bash -- it creates a temporary file and redirects from it, so I/O performance for your TMPDIR matters. It's a smaller penalty than most, but still not free. (`< <(printf '%s\n' "$time")` avoids the I/O penalty but adds a fork -- which of those is better than the other depends on the individual system; personally, I still mostly use `<<<`, since the behavior is implementation-defined and can be improved in the future).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk -v time="12:12:00" '
           function pad(x) {split(x,ax,":"); return (ax[1]<10)?"0"x:x}
                     BEGIN {time=pad(time)}
              time>pad($0) {next} 
                           {print; exit}' times


12:41:00
```

with 0 padding the hour you can do string only comparison.